# Loading a WKWebView page in advance from HTML

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm working on an app where there is a modal view containing a WKWebView. The webpage I'm displaying in the WKWebView is loaded via `self.webView.loadHTMLString` but the loading process takes too long, 5 seconds at times, and I would like to cut this time down significantly. Is there a way to preload this webpage (using `loadHTMLString`) so that when the modal is presented, the webpage is already loaded?

I've looked at all of the similar posts on Stack Overflow and none of them work in my case. The ways I've considered going about this are via caching and via calling `setNeedsLayout` in the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller that will present the modal, but haven't had any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can create a webView load the file into it , listen the delegate that the file has been loaded then pass it to the nextVc then present the next vc

Comment: call `modalViewcontroller.view layoutSubviews` to make load webpage before clicking the button

Comment: @Vinodh so I tried that in the `viewDidLoad` function of the view controller that will present the modal view but it's still not working.

Comment: @ch1maera you need to call before button click on presenting the modal view or in the page view did load where you will present the modalViewcontroller

Comment: @Vindoh Have tried both before triggering the button segue and in the `viewDidLoad` function of the page presenting the modal, neither works unfortunately.